# Call POX web service from Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

I'm using Spring Integration in a project that integrates (successfully) various ReST/JSON and SOAP endpoints.
Now I need to call a BusinessWorks instance that is configured to accept Plain-Old-Xml-over-HTTP.
From the "Spring Integration in Action book", I got a hint that I should use int-ws:outbound-gateway for this.
This configuration generates the correct request, but in SOAP:

```
<int-ws:outbound-gateway
    uri="..."
    request-channel="request" reply-channel="reply"
    marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="unmarshaller"/>
```

I can't figure out how to configure this to send the object in the payload as POX (no SOAP envelope).
I tried this:

```
<int-ws:outbound-gateway
    uri="..."
    request-channel="request" reply-channel="reply"
    marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="unmarshaller"
    message-factory="poxMessageFactory"/>
<bean id="poxMessageFactory"
    class="org.springframework.ws.pox.dom.DomPoxMessageFactory"/>
```

The request seems to switch correctly to XML only but the body of the request is empty (no trace of the object present in the Spring Integration payload).
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or how to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an omission in the `AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway`:

```
 public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {
        Object payload = this.requestMessage.getPayload();
        if (message instanceof SoapMessage) {
            this.doWithMessageInternal(message, payload);
            AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.this.headerMapper
                    .fromHeadersToRequest(this.requestMessage.getHeaders(), (SoapMessage) message);
            if (this.requestCallback != null) {
                this.requestCallback.doWithMessage(message);
            }
        }

    }
```

Pay attention to the `if (message instanceof SoapMessage) {`.

So, indeed we miss there the fact that message can be different type.

Please, open [JIRA bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) on the matter.

Meanwhile as a workaround I would suggest you to use `WebServiceTemplate` directly instead of `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` you can call it from the `<service-activator>` using `marshalSendAndReceive()` method for interaction.

Comment: Thank you! I think this authoritative answer closes the topic :-) I have opened the JIRA bug. I made only a quick attempt at using the workaround but since the service we call is managed in the same company, they accepted to reconfigure the service to accept SOAP.

Comment: Sure! The JIRA https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4355 has been fixed recently. We may release the next maintenance version asap if you need it

Comment: Oh! sorry I missed this last comment. Thank you so much, but now we can wait for a delivery in the next version.